# Datagridview Datasource is null

Tags: c#-4.0, data-binding, datagridview

Essentially I have a DGV displaying records from a List data source.  When I attempt to access the DataSource property in another function it comes up null.  I am trying to add a new record to the grid, but cannot seem to access the datasource to do so.  I have tried making the List object visible to the entire form class, but it comes up empty.  Anyone know why that is or how I can access the datasource so that I can add a new record?  Additionally, any tips on improving this code are welcome.

This is the code that fills the data into the grid:

```
SchedulingDataContext progDB = new SchedulingDataContext();

List<Attendance> attendanceRecords = new List<Attendance>();
attendanceRecords = (from a in progDB.Attendances
                     where a.ReasonCode == null
                     select a).ToList<Attendance>();

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = attendanceRecords;

AttendanceGrid.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: You need to debug this code to see if the attendanceRecords is actually populating from the LINQ query. Then go from there

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought (as I never used `BindingSource()`, I use `DataSource` and `DataBind()` ):

try adding

```
AttendanceGrid.DataBind();
```

after

```
AttendanceGrid.DataSource = bs;
```